# Detection of spots on an image, 3D-plotting of detected spots then calculate PYTHON

Tags: python, image-processing, plot, raspberry-pi3, spyder

Can someone help me on how to detect spots on an image like this on the picture using python?

[image]

After detecting the spots, there goes a red circle around and plots it as shown on the pictures attached here.

[image]

This is the 3D plot of the detected spots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model). I don't think there is a function in SciPy, but there is one in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html)

[Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html) is a tutorial on this.

(from my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069219/how-to-find-fwhm-in-a-dataset-with-multiple-peaks/49069457#49069457) question)

Of if your spots always look similar I would recommend [Template Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching). There is a [function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) in OpenCV for this. And also one in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html).